# How do I trigger a script when an Xorg session is focused?

Tags: xorg

I usually have 2 Xorg sessions running on my system, each on a different virtual terminal and with a respective system user: one for work and another one for leisure.

I do not switch among them often but when I do I must remember to turn off my time tracker software in the first session and then start it on my target session. This is because rescuetime [1] cannot listen to 2 xorg sessions at the same time.

So having some way of triggering a script everytime an Xorg session is aware that it has come into play, I could kill the running rescuetime process and start a new one.

[1] https://www.rescuetime.com

Comment: Another approach would be that instead of trying to hook into a virtual terminal switch, you write a custom script that turns the time tracking software on/off and switches to the other VT, and then you bind this script to some hotkey e.g. in your window manager.

Comment: @dirkt I thought about this but I'm afraid that I would easily forget about switching hence I'd have some misleading data in my timetracker.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to script something around

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -e modify /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active
case "$(cat /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active)" in
    tty7) <dothis> ;;
    tty8) <dothat> ;;
esac
exec $0 $*
```

The "file" `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active` tells which virtual console is the active one, in terms of `tty7` or `tty1` etc., and it's changed when you shift from one to another. The `inotifywait` command simply waits until there's a `modify` event for that pathname, so the script may then inspect which one it is for doing its associated thing. Thereafter (the `exec` line) the script reinvokes itself for capturing the next virtual console transition.

On a Debian based Linux, you find `inotifywait` as part of the `inotify-tools` package. The `/sys/..` pathname requires a duly mounted `sysfs`, which generally belongs to the Linux kernel since yonks ago.

Comment: This is a very good starting point, thanks.